# Dynamically update the list of files in a folder

Tags: tomcat, directory-listing

What is the best way to achieve this ? I have a tomcat server and the files are uploaded to the `WEB-INF` folder and  I used to write a html file (index.html) and add the files manually. I enabled directory listing in Tomcat but when I type in `http://127.0.0.1/test_server/WEB-INF/`  I get a 404 , if I move the files to test_server instead of `WEB-INF` and if I go to `http://127.0.0.1/test_server/` The file gets listed there so how do I get it to work when I navigate to `WEB-INF` folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"TheWEB-INF directory is not part of the public document tree of the application. No file contained in theWEB-INF directory can be served directly to a client by the container. However, the contents of theWEB-INF directory are visible to servlet code using the getResource and getResourceAsStream() method calls onthe ServletContextorincludes/forwardsusingthe RequestDispatcher."

More explanation ca be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/configurewebapp.html

So you should use a different directory if you want to enable directory listing.

Comment: So if I were to have something like this `http://127.0.0.1/test_server/Uploads/`
should that fix the issue ?

Comment: well that seems to be showing what I  have in the folder, next question is do I have to write a script that updates the list of files ? By the looks of it I don't think I need to. What do you think is the  proper conduct :D

Comment: If you just want to list files in the directory, you don't need to do anything.